# UIPageviewcontroller transition style scroll continuous

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

The default pageviewcontroller scroll transition style does a flip. How do I make the scroll continuous or smooth?

Comment: What do you mean by continuous? You mean you don't want the user to be able to pause in the middle of the animation?

Comment: Correct. Something like iBooks vertical scroll in iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a continuous scroll, what you can have is paginated scrolling meaning that the PageViewController will always snap to a particular page. See the types:

```
UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl = 0, // Navigate between views via a page curl transition.
UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
```

Perhaps what you are looking for is a UIScrollView or UICollectionView (Meaning you are going to need to write your own continuous scrolling component)

Comment: How is it done in iBooks app? I have also seen couple of apps having similar transitions..ex. Olive tree app

Comment: @Freddy as i said in my answer, if you are looking for a different implementation you will need to write your own. UICollectionView is definitely the least amount of effort. Its possible that Apple have private API to do this